# PHPMailer and php send mail not supported

Tags: php, email

I'm triyng to implement a reserved area in my website, with an automatic registration notification and password recovery using a php script for sending e-mail.
My provider told me that php send mail is not supported, so I switched to PHPMailer class in order to use Google SMTP server.
Since I can't make it working I wonder if I'm doing a right choice.
My questions are :

1. Can I use PHPMailer if my provider doesn't support php send mail?
2. Can I use my PHPMailer script from my localhost to test the procedure before deploying it on the provider server?

Mant thanks on advance.
Dom

Answer (score 0):

Yes to the second one. But I don't think so for the first one. I have used phpmailer for a long time now including on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, that you could use PHPMailer to send mail, even if your host doesn't support "send mail". I think he actually ment the sendmail() functions, which is usually a native function. But PHPMailer is using it's own independant implementation.

I use PHPMailer with the SMTP host of my hosting provider. For GMail, there are some special settings you have to make. You can find a [basic example](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebgmail) and [a more advanched one](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleagmail) on the PHPMailer website.

Comment: Thanks. I used your indications, but I get the following error "SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.". I suspect that my hosting provider doesn't support SLL/TLS authorization

Answer (score 0):

Most web hosting have PHP mail() function as
I also faced same issue I know it's solution

If you have PHP core then you have absolutely mail function also
Try my sample code below

> ```
>   <?php
>   // the message
>   $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";
>    // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
>   $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
>   // send email
>   mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
>   ?>
> ```